# how to play in a table which play so loose and mostly limp without any kind of standards?

Tags: texas-hold-em

i want to know how we should play at a table which most of players just limp and call and some times goes all in and you usually never see any kind of standard playing? shoud we play like them and every time limp and call or we should play in standard way and dont pay attention to their way of playing?

thank you
best wishes
merda

Comment: How do you play it.  Play it often.  Play it tight.  And when you have a hand raise.

Answer (score 3):

If the table is mostly loose you want to tighten up your gameplay.  Whereas if the table is tight you generally want to play a bit looser.  As a general rule.

Are they actually playing reckless or are they taking advantage of a tight table?

If they are playing recklessly then you want to tighten up and wait for position and hands.  If they are playing loose at a tight table then you might have to loosen up your range to compete with them.

Playing loose is not a bad strategy, it's more risk, but if a loose player has phenomenal after flop play they can make a killing.  Take Tom Dwan for example.  Very loose aggressive player.

Me personally?  I punish limpers.  If someone limps my hand range expands to what hands I will raise with.  I'm a bit of an aggressive player however.  Whatever strategy you adopt it has to be one you are comfortable with or you will shout tells that something is off.

Answer (score 1):

I built my initial bankroll playing freerolls in this sort of environment so perhaps I may have some helpful input. "Low and slow is all you need to know" would be how I summarize play at such tables.
Some absurd number of players are going to call you down no matter what the flop is, no matter how weak their hand is... This is good but it makes for, in my opinion, a slow game. Some would claim 9 or 10 handed is no slower a poker game than 6 handed. Much more time can be spent analyzing the opponents method of play to discover their tendencies and thus places at which we may play at them. This is, most would agree, a very large part of poker. Agree I must, however, I like to be in pots. Lots of posts. Unfortunately, this low and slow ABC style of play is the only certain way, as far as I can tell, to crush these sort of games.

Step one is easy! Stay in position. People tend to get board and attempt to get lucky with junk hands in poor positions. Just don't. This alone started taking me consistently well past the first break.

Step two is never slowplay, never bluff. Look down and see two aces? Raise. Flop comes dry, raise. They call and the turn pairs the board...raise. They're calling everything all the time anyways right? Put it in when you got it, take that stack. Didn't flop a hand? Check. They checked both the turn and the river? Probably gonna want to check again. Let them take an insignificant 8-10BB pot with their pair of 4's no kicker. You take the 35BB pot with your nut flush.

Step three is to remember poker is a game of probabilities. (Oh! the frustrations of the suck outs...how I remember you so vividly.) Even A's aren't a sure win. You will see plenty of people 'get lucky.' They will do it against you. Your goal is not to win every tournament, it's to get your money in 'with the best of it.' If you get it in KK against QQ on a dry flop where K's were overs, pat yourself on the back no matter what the result of the hand. The best way, in this style of game, to get it in with the best of it, is ABC poker. Yes, it's slow. Yes, it requires lots of time, regular and scheduled play, often for near nothing. Yes it takes months and months to build a bankroll this way... The learning experience is worth it.